# Playing Age of Mythology on Windows 10

Tags: backwards-compatibility, windows-10, age-of-mythology

I am a big fan of Age of Mythology and it worked perfectly on my computer on Windows 7. A few weeks ago I upgraded to Windows 10 and now I get the below  error message:

> ACCESS DENIED - Please login with administrator privileges and try again

I've already tried a couple of things, but nothing worked for me.

- I checked if my account is administrator and it is.
- I tried copying the `secdrv.sys` file from the CD to `system32/drivers` -> no solution
- I tried running it in compatibility mode and then nothing happens.
- I tried using command prompt to by pass the secdrv security as per this video:

  -> last step was blocked, so I don't know what to do.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried this (at your own risk): [How to Disable Driver Verifier on Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/1006441/how-to-disable-driver-verifier-on-windows-10) and then [this](http://windowsreport.com/cd-games-windows-10/): *Solution 5 – Add SafeDisc driver manually*? But you own the disk, so would it be "safer" to do [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-disc_crack)?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Age of Mythology from its original DVD, it might not work with Windows 10. I suggest getting the [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/266840/) version instead.

You can also try to update the game using its files, I think there is an updater somewhere in there.

Comment: @Michthan Agreed. But that way, you can get [Age of Mythology + Titans + Tale of the Dragon](http://store.steampowered.com/app/266840/) -75% or [Microsoft RTS Collection](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/91439/) -75% right now! It's Steam Sales!

Comment: Do you know how long it lasts? Maybe I can ask it for Christmas m?

Comment: There's no "might", It WILL not work unless you effectively downgrade your system one way or another. "[...] safedisc is a very old technology and is no longer supported. It's not something we can just make compatible on newer versions of windows since no third party is supporting it." – [Microsoft Employee](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/games_windows_10/age-of-mythology-windows-10/c7142024-8298-4060-aeb8-0e77d9d83af7?page=3) Apparently including third party companies owned by Microsoft that, considering the new EE release, are now deincentivised to provide a patch to do so.